# Need continuous rank of marks

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to get continuous rank of marks from following marks.

```
100
90
80
70
70
70
60
60
50
45
48
47
37
33
```

---

```
=RANK(A2,$A$2:$A$15)
```

Above `Rank()` formula gives rank of mark but discontinuous. Following screenshot will clear what I am try to say.

> I am looking for solution with built in excel formulas only. No `VBA`.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try as follow:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(
    (FREQUENCY($A$2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A)),
    $A$2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A))) > 0) * (A2 <= $A$2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A)+1)) 
)
```

[image: Result of dense rank built formula]

Comment: Thanks. The formula works for. I will wait for while if there is easier formula either will accept your answer. Right now upvoting...

Answer (score 1):

As long as the data remains sorted in a descending manner, you really just need a progressive unique count.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(A$2:A2, A$2:A2))
```

[image]

Comment: Each row is getting a unique count of values from that row and all rows above. It isn't a true ranking because the apparent ranking is really due to the descending sort. You are getting a unique count of the values that are larger.